# How to make the selected Tab center in TabBar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my TabBar, there are up to 3 kinds of tabs of different widths.

"x月xx" has the widest width, "xx月" is the middle, "x月" has the narrowest width.

And when the tab state change from unselected to selected, it will become more wide because it add the prefix "xxxx年" to the title.

[image: I can not set a specific value to tab width, because the tab title may change from "2020年11月" to "11月" if unselected.]

I can not set a specific value to tab width, because the tab title may change from "2020年11月" to "11月" if unselected.

**My purpose is to center the selected tab on the screen.**

The method `animateTo` of `TabController` only allows scrolling to an index but not a distance. So I copied the `tabs.dart`. I want to change the method `_scrollToCurrentIndex()` which uses a `ScrollController` to animate to an offset. There are many things(e.g. various TabOffsets, ScrollOffset, viewportWidth...) useful, but I still don' t know how to let scroll offset and padding work together.

Comment: Do you have a diagram or example of exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Can you try wrapping the widget with the container and provide the size to the container..in this way you will be having the widgets size .....its just a wayaround

Comment: @lsaudon Edited. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vinamra Jaiswal The widget has dynamic width.

Comment: you can get some idea [here](https://flutteragency.com/how-to-customize-tabbar-width-in-flutter/)

Comment: @gretal thanks, but this has absolutely nothing to do with my question

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded partly, that means, the selected tab will scroll to center, but the animation is strange.

In `class _TabBarState extends State<TabBar>` I found this in build function:

```
Widget tabBar = CustomPaint(
  painter: _indicatorPainter,
  child: _TabStyle(
    // ...
    child: _TabLabelBar(
      onPerformLayout: _saveTabOffsets,
      children: wrappedTabs,
    ),
  ),
);
```

In `onPerformLayout: _saveTabOffsets` I can get `List<double> tabOffsets` and `double tabBarWidth`. I use these to calculate the distance to scroll. But in this way, the problem is: when click a tab, it draws the indicator first, and after the indicator change from the last selected tab to the new selected tab, the tabBar scrolls to center it.

I am open to better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following option for your `TabBar`:
`tabAlignment: TabAlignment.center`